# Checkbox not working within mapping function react js css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, checkbox

I have a mapping function within modifiers.js, that is used by itemlist to show checkboxes inside a pop up, after doing this mapping function, the checkbox stopped working. I think it is the CSS (hidden checkbox communication) because it works well without CSS.

**Modifiers.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Modifiers.css";

//import "./Modifiers.scss";

const Modifiers = props => {
  const id = props.childId + props.childp
  return (
    <form className="form">
      <div>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
          <div className="inputGroup">
          {props.options && props.options.map(item => {
              console.log(item)
                return (
                    <div>
                      <label for={id}>{item.name}</label>
                      <input
                      id={id}
                      name="checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                    />
                    </div>
                )
              })}
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Modifiers;
```

Modifiers.css

```
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3c454c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #5562eb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.inputGroup label:after {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #d1d7dc;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label {
  color: #fff;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label:after {
  background-color: #54e0c7;
  border-color: #54e0c7;
}
.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.form {
  padding: 0 16px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 36px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
code {
  background-color: #9aa3ac;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

and the rest of the code you can find it on codebox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/p32k93k660?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Comment: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar in which div do you mean?

Comment: @Alpub it's <label htmlFor={id}> not <label for={id}> try this once

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar I've done that already and nothing changed

Comment: Your CodeSandbox link appears to be broken. Nothing is rendering. Hard to help with this.

Comment: @AndyHoffman you have to switch from project view to current view and click on app.js,  the switch button can be found on top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes done: changed the html structure, used opacity instead of visibility and the check should be above the circle(customized checkbox) so it should be checked when you click on the circle. hope this helps. thanks

try add below code

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input id="undefinedCoke" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label htmlfor="undefinedCoke">Coke</label>
    </div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.inputGroup input {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    order: 1;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 31px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
```